# Find length of json data

Tags: json, jqxgrid

I am having this data

```
    var initialData = [
        { name: "Sweets", details: 352 },
        { name: "Spicy", details: "89 juwu jdbjd jd bdjh djh sdjh sjh sdhj sjh sjh shjdsjhsdhjsdhjshjdyrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr" },
        { name: "Salty", details: 23 }
```

];

Have to find the maximum length of 'details' field and get the output as 70(suppose length of details for name:'spicy') i.e maximum value .Need Solutions/Suggestions . Thanxs in advance .

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the way out , answering as it may help somebody in future................ 
first take the count of your array

```
var count = 0; for (var p in initialData) { if (initialData.hasOwnProperty(p)) { count++; } }
```

Fetch initialdata particular element and use loop to get max value

```
   var wid = 0; for (i = 0; i <= count-1; i++) { var temp1 = initialData[i].details.length; wid = wid > temp1 ? wid : temp1; }
```